# React redux mapped state to props array is null on update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to update a user's profile via a form and make sure the component is rerendered on update and the correct information is displaying on the form after saving. This is what I have so far:

ProfileInput.tsx

```
const ProfileInput = ({ user }: any) => {

   const updateHandler = () => {
        let action;

        action = UserAction.updateUser(
            formState.inputValues.name  
        )

        setError(null);
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            dispatch(action);
            setSaveIsDisabled(true);
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err.message);
            setIsLoading(false); 
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
    }      
  
    if(!user[0]) {
       return (<p>loading....</p>);
    }
    

        return (
        <ProfileInputContainer>
            <ProfileInputInnerContainer>
                <Form>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Group controlId="formGroupName">
                                <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                                <Input
                                    authid="name"
                                    type="text"
                                    required
                                    minLength={5}
                                    autoCapitalize="none"
                                    errortext="Name must be at least 5 characters long."
                                    inputchange={inputChangeHandler}
                                    errorhandler={errorHandler}
                                    placeholder="Enter your full name"
                                    initialvalue={user[0].name} />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                 </Form>
                 <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <CustomButtonContainer>
                            <CustomButton
                                fillColour={saveIsDisabled ? Colours.light_grey : Colours.green}
                                disabled={saveIsDisabled}
                                onClick={updateHandler}
                            >
                                {isLoading ? '...loading' : 'Save'}
                            </CustomButton>
                        </CustomButtonContainer>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </ProfileInputContainer>
        </ProfileInputInnerContainer>
    )

   
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    user: state.user.userData
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(ProfileInput)
```

Upon loading the page the user's name is fetched fine from state. The problem I'm having is when clicking save and dispatching to the SET_USER action, it looks like `if(!user[0])` is satisfied as all I can see is 'loading...'. I'm not sure why as I console.log out user and I see the correct data.

user reducer:

```
export const userReducer = (state: any = initialState, action: any) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_USER:
            return { userData: action.userData }
        default:
            return state;
    }
    
    return state;
```

The component must be rerendering as it reloads and shows the loading message but I'm not entirely sure why it hits the loading message. Could someone point out where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: what is contents of ```action.userData```?

Comment: Did you try using ```useSelector```? ```const {userData: users} = useSelector(state => state.user);```

Comment: Thanks @sivako, your question made me realise that on initial load its contents is an array but it's an object after it's updated by redux. So user[0] is never found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your props into state and then do the if-else to return.

React will only render when there is a change in React state.

Currently, your change is only at props which is `user`.

You will have to use `useEffect` to detect the change of user props and update user state which will lead to re-rendering of the component.

Like this.

```
const [userState,setUserState] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

    setUserState(user);

    },[user]);
```

I give this example since you are using `connect` which is a higher-order component of Redux to map redux state into your component props.

However, you can always opt for `useSelecter` hook.

```
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.userData);
```

Then you don't need the `useEffect` since the `useSelector` already return a state inside your functional component as a re-render pivot. You can leave the `connect` and `mapStateToProps` out of the picture also and just `export const ProfileInput`

By the way,

You should spread your state in your reducer.

```
case SET_USER:
            return { ...state, userData: action.userData }
```

Comment: Thanks, I did originally have it like this and took it off to see if that made a difference.

Comment: try my new ans :) @Nats